# Synonym request: [conflict] ← [arguments]

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I believe that [arguments](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arguments) is an exact synonym of [conflict](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict), which is the more prevalent tag.

Comment: There's also "fighting". I wanted to retag the current question on that topic earlier and then got confused by the tags...

Answer (score 2):

[I proposed arguments as a synonym of conflict.](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tags/conflict/synonyms)

I am a little less sure about fighting, which could be a legitimate subset (I interpret it as fistfights with other kids, although that is hardly the only interpretation possible) -- without a definition for [fighting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fighting) it's a bit harder to know how the community sees that.

Comment: There's also "violence".  I like and agree with your interprettin of violence.